# Angular ng serve Fails at 10% Building, 'DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser')', and Hash Algorithm Erro

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, deprecation-warning

I'm experiencing the "DeprecationWarning" error and Hash Algorithm Error when running ng serve in my Angular project. I've tried various solutions, but the issue persists.

Here's what I've tried:

- Deleted node_modules and reinstalled dependencies with npm install.
- Used different Node.js versions, including LTS versions like 16.14.2 and 18.13.0 (current).
- Upgraded Angular CLI to the latest version (17.0.7).
- Tried different Angular versions, including the latest (17.0.7).
- Cleared npm cache with npm cache clean --force.
- Set the NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider environment variable (temporary workaround).
  Error Details:

10% building 3/4 modules 1 active ...erver/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-nodenode:internal/crypto/hash:71
this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
... (stack trace continues)

Node.js v18.13.0
Angular CLI v17.0.7

Additional Information:

Operating System: Ub
Webpack version: 9.1.13

package.json file -

```
{
  "name": "frontend2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.13",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.13",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.13",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```